# Error when trying to include SafetyNet recaptcha api in android project

Tags: android, recaptcha

I am developing an android application where I wish to include reCaptcha functionality. I read about it in the documentation and got the site and secret key.
The problem is whenever I include this SafetyNet recaptcha api in my project I get an error eveytime I try to run it.
The error says

> Process 'command' /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java returned with non
>   zero exit value 1

I know this is because the recaptcha api because I removed it and the error was gone and then I again included it, the error came back again.

Thanks in advance,
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you use embedded JDK?(could view this in project structure - sdk location)

Comment: Yes right now I am using embedded JDK, but I have tried using the oracle jdk I have installed in the system and it gives the same error for that one too

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here, turns out I had different versions of safetynet api and the firebase api and when I synced these versions the error was gone.